# Salesforce SOQL query is failing randomly at different times

Tags: soql

We facing the issue regarding SOQL Query Operation from our product Somtimes fails or Sometimes not.2 queries which are "same" - once run in the night schedule and one in the morning manually but gives result one fails and one retrive records.Please refer follwing logs. 
Is this known issue of SOQL salesforce?

> 19/06/2018 20:30:09.104 93: Query SOQL

`'SELECT Id, Name, Credit_Request__r.JDE_Document_Number__c, Item_Number__c, Quantity_Credited__c, Adjusted_Unit_Price__c, Order_Line_Number__c, Invoice_Number__c, Invoice_Type__c FROM Order_Line_Error__c WHERE Credit_Request__r.Submit_to_JDE__c = true AND Credit_Request__r.Generate_Line__c = false AND Credit_Request__r.JDE_Processing_Status__c = 'Waiting for submission' AND Credit_Request__r.JDE_Document_Number__c <> '`''

> 19/06/2018 20:30:09.331 93: Query result - No records found.

---

---The problem  above here it shows NO RECORDS FOUND but records exists.

The same query when triggered at different time again manually worked well.Please refer the follwing log

> 20/06/2018 09:33:33.637 96: Query SOQL

`'SELECT Id, Name, Credit_Request__r.JDE_Document_Number__c, Item_Number__c, Quantity_Credited__c, Adjusted_Unit_Price__c, Order_Line_Number__c, Invoice_Number__c, Invoice_Type__c FROM Order_Line_Error__c WHERE Credit_Request__r.Submit_to_JDE__c = true AND Credit_Request__r.Generate_Line__c = false AND Credit_Request__r.JDE_Processing_Status__c = 'Waiting for submission' AND Credit_Request__r.JDE_Document_Number__c <> '`''

> 20/06/2018 09:33:33.865 96: Query result size 31. 20/06/2018
>   09:33:33.865 96: ... chunk size - 31 records.  QueryLocator = null

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also check the access of a user who has created the Scheduled Job, and the class is of type withSharing or WithoutSharing.

Comment: The user context is critical here, especially if "manually" means the query is run in the Developer Console.